# jQuery validation method for group of check boxes with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a group of checkboxes that due to the integration with another platform must have separate names although they are all related.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 checkbox-group">
      <label class="block input-group" for="Field5">Type of Insurance<span class="required-mark">*</span></label>
      <span><input type="checkbox" name="Field5" class="validate checkbox-group" value="Auto" >Auto</span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" name="Field6" class="validate checkbox-group"  value="Home" >Home</span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" name="Field7" class="validate checkbox-group"  value="Auto &amp; Home" >Home</span>
      <span><input type="checkbox" name="Field8" class="validate checkbox-group" value="Renters">Condo, Co-op,Renters</span>
</div>
```

Generally you could use Field[] and validate that within the jQuery validation rules and set it to required. I can't set every field to required as only one of the checkboxes must be checked but they can all also be checked.

That leads me to believe I will need a custom method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkone", function(){
    if( $(".checkbox-group").is(":checked") ){
      return true;
    }
    return false; 
}, "Please check at least of one");
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make just one error message appear on screen. The validation works but outputs four separate errors when none of the checkboxes are checked.

The rule is added to every checkbox

`$(this).rules('add', { checkone: true }`);

Comment: You can either stop the checks once an error is returned and output it, or set a boolean from false to true so any followup checks are skipped. Or you can check your error array for duplicate values and remove them. There are quite a few reasonably simple solutions for this.

Comment: @icecub I was looking for a native way within then jQuery validation library. I guess I will go with the boolean method.

Comment: Well you could return a boolean instead of an error message. Then output the error if the boolean is set to true later. I think that would be the most elegant solution.

Comment: Read the docs.  You missed the `groups` option, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks don't know how I missed that. It worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I can't seem to figure out is how to make just one error message appear on screen. The validation works but outputs four separate errors when none of the checkboxes are checked.

You can use [the `groups` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) within `.validate()` to combine all error messages into one.

```
$('#yourForm').validate({
    groups: {
        anyName: "Field5 Field6 Field7 Field8"
    },
    // other options, etc.
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/x2ezo033/](http://jsfiddle.net/x2ezo033/)**

Then you can use a conditional function within [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place it anywhere within your layout.